# Collapsing a data frame over one variable

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a data frame in the following format:

```
Site    Year    Month   Count1  Count2  Count3  Patch
1        1        May     15      12      10      1
1        1        May     8        0      5       2
1        1        May     3         1      2      3
1        1        May     4        4      1       4
1        1        June    6       5       1       1
1        1        June    9        1      3       2
1        1        June    3       0       0       3
1        1        June    5       5       2       4
1        1        July    4       0       3       1
..........
```

And I wish to collapse the data frame across the levels of patch such that the three count variables are summed. i.e.

```
Site    Year    Month   Count1  Count2  Count3  
1        1        May     30      17      18     
1        1        June    23      11       6       
1        1        July     4       0       3      
.........
```

I've looked at the aggregate and tapply commands, but they do not seem to sum across patch as required.

Can somebody please advise on a command that will convert the data accordingly.

Thank you.

Comment: ??? What is the role you expect "patch" to play? `aggregate` would give you this output with no problem....

Comment: You apparently want to sum over not just patch but over patch, year, site and month. Your failure with aggregate probably stems from not being able to describe the full specification correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. All three methods work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With aggregate:

```
> ( a <- aggregate(.~Site+Year+Month, dat[-length(dat)], sum) )
#   Site Year Month Count1 Count2 Count3
# 1    1    1  July      4      0      3
# 2    1    1  June     23     11      6
# 3    1    1   May     30     17     18
```

Where `dat` is your data.

Note that your July results in the post are seem to be incorrect.

For the result in the order of the original data, you can use

```
> a[order(as.character(unique(dat$Month))), ]
#   Site Year Month Count1 Count2 Count3
# 3    1    1   May     30     17     18
# 2    1    1  June     23     11      6
# 1    1    1  July      4      0      3
```

Comment: another way to keep the order `aggregate(dat[-3], by = with(dat, list(Site, Year, factor(Month, levels = unique(Month)))), sum)`

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr) 
dat %>% 
group_by(Site, Year, Month) %>% 
summarise_each(funs(sum=sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), Count1:Count3)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
#Groups: Site, Year

#    Site Year Month Count1 Count2 Count3
#  1    1    1  July      4      0      3  
#  2    1    1  June     23     11      6
#  3    1    1   May     30     17     18
```

Answer (score 3):

Or `data.table` solution (which will keep your data sorted by the original month order)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), 
            by = list(Site, Year, Month), 
            .SDcols = paste0("Count", seq_len(3))]

#    Site Year Month Count1 Count2 Count3
# 1:    1    1   May     30     17     18
# 2:    1    1  June     23     11      6
# 3:    1    1  July      4      0      3
```

Comment: The fact that it comes back in the original order is a really nice feature.

Comment: @RichardScriven, you can do either way. If you want it sorted, do `keyby` instead of `by`

Comment: Alternatively: `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD,sum), by=list(Site,Year,Month), .SDcols=-"Patch"]`